# In geom_bezier2, specifying size as a function of plot coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2, size, bezier, ggforce

In `geom_bezier2()`, in what units is `size` and can I specify it as a function of the plot coordinates?

```
library(ggplot2); library(ggforce)

beziers <- 
  data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
    type = rep('quadratic', 4),
    point = c('end', 'control', 'control', 'end')
)

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("orange", "blue"))

ggplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_bezier2(aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   group = type),
               size = seq(35, 3, length.out = 100), # respecify as function of plot coordinates?
               color = colfunc(100),
               alpha = .4,
               data = beziers)
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge and the docs of ggplot2 the unit of `size` is `mm`, i.e. "The size of a line is its width in mm." Source: [here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#lines).

And yes. Using the `after_stat` function introduced in `ggplot2 3.3.0` you can specify `size` as a function of the plot coordinates.

As an example and to clarifiy the difference I made four plots. First plot the result of your code. Second plot maps a complicated function of x on size which essentially has no effect on the plotted sizes. Plots 3 and 4 use `after_stat`. Plot 3 maps the interpolated x values computed by `geom/stat_bezier2` on size while plot 4 applies a log transformation.

```r
library(ggplot2); library(ggforce); library(patchwork)

beziers <- 
  data.frame(
    x = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
    y = c(1, 1, 0, 0),
    type = rep('quadratic', 4),
    point = c('end', 'control', 'control', 'end')
  )

colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("orange", "blue"))

# Setting size and color as functions of x using after_stat
p1 <- ggplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_bezier2(aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   group = type),
               size = seq(35, 3, length.out = 100), # respecify as function of plot coordinates?
               color = colfunc(100),
               alpha = .4,
               data = beziers) + 
  labs(title = "Original plot")

p2 <- ggplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_bezier2(aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   group = type, 
                   size = exp(log(x)^2 + 10)),
               color = colfunc(100),
               alpha = .4,
               data = beziers) +
  scale_size(range = c(35, 3)) +
  guides(size = FALSE) + 
  labs(title = "exp(log(x)^2 + 10) mapped on size")

p3 <- ggplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_bezier2(aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   group = type, 
                   size = after_stat(x)),
               color = colfunc(100),
               alpha = .4,
               data = beziers) +
  scale_size(range = c(35, 3)) +
  guides(size = FALSE) + 
  labs(title = "x mapped on size using after stat")

p4 <- ggplot() + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1.5)) +
  geom_bezier2(aes(x = x, y = y, 
                   group = type, 
                   size = after_stat(log(x))),
               color = colfunc(100),
               alpha = .4,
               data = beziers) +
  scale_size(range = c(35, 3)) +
  guides(size = FALSE)  + 
  labs(title = "log(x) mapped on size using after stat")

(p1 + p2) / (p3 + p4)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I don't see how the code edit respecified size as a function of the plot coordinates as running the original code example and yours seem to have the same result. Try running your code at different plot sizes and you'll see the line size isn't a function of plot size.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you are trying to achieve. However, at least my example was not well chosen. I just edited my post to clarify how using `after_stat` allows to specify size as a function of x.

Comment: Let me try again. Plot coordinates are mapped to pixels in a display and so the location of plot coordinates depends on display size. The line size, unlike plot coordinates, are specified in mm regardless of plot size. Try resizing the plot, and you'll see that the line size is not a function of the plot coordinates. I'd like the size to map to plot coordinates. So that, say in your example above, the left yellow line ends around y-coordinate spans ~ [0.5,1.5] regardless of plot resizing.